# Why can't hostapd find my fresh installed r8188eu driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, raspberrypi, hostapd

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on an Raspberry 3B. I want to use an TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 as an Hotspot (I know that its possible because it was already used as an AP on another RPI3B running Raspbian)

So I mainly followed this [tutorial](https://michaelmuenzer.medium.com/create-an-ap-to-gain-remote-control-of-the-raspberry-7ff7a81ebbe0). I downloaded the repo and installed the driver like this:

```
sudo make all
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

There are several files in `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi` now, but I think the two relevant are those:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  11216 Apr 11 14:26 rtl8188efw.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  13904 May 18 10:11 rtl8188eufw.bin
```

It's also shown when using lsmod:

```
root@ubuntu:# lsmod | grep 88
8188eu                811008  0
```

The device is also shown on lsusb:

```
root@ubuntu:# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
```

Now for the hotspot, I used my working config for the built-in wifi adapter and changed it to wlan1 and the new driver:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=r8188eu
ssid=myssid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=mypass
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Then when running hostapd I get the error:

```
root@ubuntu:# hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'r8188eu'
```

That's it. I also made sure that there no weird line ending characters.

Can someone tell me what went wrong? Why can't it find the driver I just installed?

---

edit1:

Output of iw list (cut):

```
Wiphy phy1
        max # scan SSIDs: 10
        max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
        max # match sets: 16
        max # scan plans: 1
        max scan plan interval: 508
        max scan plan iterations: 0
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports roaming.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
```

and the usb-devices command:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ usb-devices | awk '/010c/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=010c Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=00E04C0001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=8188eu
```

---

edit2:

When using `nl80211`, I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Could not set channel for kernel driver
Interface initialization failed
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED
wlan1: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

---

edit3: It works now. I brought the wlan1 interface up via `ifconfig wlan1 up`.

Comment: Please add output of `iw list` command to your question. This will check if the driver supports AP mode.

Comment: Also please post output of `usb-devices | awk '/010c/' RS=` command.

Comment: All looks good.

Comment: @Pilot6 So why can't it find the driver?

Comment: Change driver to `driver=nl80211`

Comment: Please add output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: @Pilot6 wlan1 was not up, I brought it up and then it started working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo here:

```
driver=r8188eu
```

It should be

```
driver=nl80211
```

The `hostapd` manual says:

> Driver interface type (hostap/wired/none/nl80211/bsd);
> default: hostap). nl80211 is used with all Linux mac80211 drivers.

Comment: I already tried that, but same problem: `Line 2: invalid/unknown driver '8188eu'`

Comment: Okay I changed it back, but now it's a different error (see updated question please)

Comment: Maybe `wlan` is wrong as an interface name. Check what is the real name.